# Parse -xml for variable

Tags: xml-parsing

I’m using a cluster system that when I

> qstat -xml 
>   I get a bunch of
>   tag-VARIABLE-tag

How do I parse this command for extraction of multiple VARIABLEs?

Comment: Can you post a few of the examples and your desired output?

Comment: Imagine I submit the >qstat -xml command and it gives me the following:<job_list state="running">
      <JB_job_number>11011</JB_job_number>
      <JAT_prio>0.60500</JAT_prio>                                                                       I want be able to pull the job number

Comment: I want be able to pull the JB_job_number and  JAT_prio. So I want essentially the 11011 and 0.60500

Comment: The response for the qstat command seems invalid (for example, there's no closing tag for `<job_list>`. Check again and repost.